# Firebase delete user: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Ionic2 with Firebase Database (AngularFire2).

When a user deletes their user profile, it deletes correctly from the Firebase Authentication.

```
user: firebase.User
...
user.delete().then(() => {
```

However, then I get the following error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /chat:
>   Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. Error:
>   permission_denied at /chat: Client doesn't have permission to access
>   the desired data.

I don't access the Firebase Database after I delete the user, but there are ongoing subscriptions.

**Question**

Is there a way to de-register a user from the Firebase database when they are deleted so that I don't get the error above?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is some more info:

```
this.dataService.deleteChatsAndMessagesForUid(personModel.uid).then(() => {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            user.delete().then(() => {
```

where

```
deleteChatsAndMessagesForUid(uid: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        let promiseArray: Promise<any>[] = [];
        promiseArray.push(this.firebaseDataService.deleteChatsAndMessagesForUid(uid));
        promiseArray.push(this.localDataService.deleteChatsAndMessagesForUid(uid));
        Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => {
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
}
```

I also put breakpoints on each database call, and none are fired after the `user.delete`.

Comment: Can't you delete the chat DB entries before delete rather than within the callback?

Comment: I do delete the Chat entries before I delete the user. That's why I don't understand why I am getting the error. To test it, I delete the Chat entries, then window.setTimeout for 5 seconds before I delete the user. But I still get the above error. I even put in breakpoints on any database call, and none are fired after I do the delete user. So I am confused by the above error.

Comment: Could you show us the code within the promise response?

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my code above.

Comment: This may be similar to something I came across recently where I was trying to do a Firebase action within the callback response of another Firebase action and getting errors. I was able to get around it in my case by doing the calls in parallel. So user.delete(); chatsDelete();

Comment: Doing the calls in parallel will be non-deterministic. You should complete the parts that depend on auth before deleting the auth account. @Richard Did you try off() to stop listening on the db paths and prevent the error?

Comment: Hi @Kato, what do I call off() on?

Comment: @Kato That's true. In my case I'm doing database operations so it's not really what Richard is trying to achieve. Interesting you mention off().

Comment: You can use a first() function to detach from the Observable. Please see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851369/observable-confusion/42851603#42851603