# Observable Confusion

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using `Ionic2` with `AngularFire2`.

I am also making use of a `rxjs` `Observable`. I have the following code:

```
findChatsForUid(uid: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('/chat/', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
        }
    }).map(items => {
        const filtered = items.filter(
            item => (item.memberId1 === uid || item.memberId2 === uid)
        );
        return filtered;
    });
}
```

and

```
deleteChatsAndMessagesForUid(uid: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
        let promiseArray: Promise<any>[] = [];
        this.findChatsForUid(uid).map(items => {
            return items;
        }).forEach((chatItems) => {
            for (let i: number = 0; i < chatItems.length; i++) {
                promiseArray.push(this.deleteChat(chatItems[i], true));
            }
            Promise.all(promiseArray).then(() => {
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

In the second function, you can see I retrieve the `Observable` from the first, and the loop through each item using the `forEach` function.

My problem is, because this is an `Observable`, there is always a handle to the object. So when I do the following:

```
deleteChatsAndMessagesForUid(uid).then(() => {
    user.delete().then(() => {
        ...
    }
}
```

It results in the following error because the deleted user is still trying to observe the `Observable`.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /chat:
>   Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. Error:
>   permission_denied at /chat: Client doesn't have permission to access
>   the desired data.

**Question**

Is there a way to retrieve the data, without still being attached to the `Observable`? So that I am free to delete the associated user?  Or is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to unsubsribe from the `list` observable after the first emitted list.

You can use the `first` operator to complete the `list` observable after the first emitted list. This will result in automatic unsubscription and the listeners will be removed from the internal Firebase ref.

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

findChatsForUid(uid: string): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.af.database
    .list('/chat/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
      }
    })
    .first()
    .map(items => {
      const filtered = items.filter(
        item => (item.memberId1 === uid || item.memberId2 === uid)
      );
      return filtered;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the first() function did it.